# IF Statement on an Object of outerText

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, queryselector

Not sure if I'm asking this correctly but I want to retrieve and store subtext from this class "infobox__column" that has a Nodelist of up to 12.

```
  <p><strong>Applications Open:&nbsp;</strong>01 May 2023</p>
  <p><strong>Applications Close:&nbsp;</strong>15 June 2023</p>
  <p><strong>Next Available Intake:&nbsp;</strong>July 2023</p>
  <p><strong>Course Types:&nbsp;</strong>Modular Undergraduate Course</p>
  <p><strong>Language:&nbsp;</strong>English</p>


  <p><strong>Duration:&nbsp;</strong>6 months</p>
  <p><strong>Fees:&nbsp;</strong>$1536 <a href="/courses/admissions/tuition-fees" title="View More Details on Fees">View More Details on Fees</a></p>
  <p><strong>Area of Interest:&nbsp;</strong>Business Administration</p>
  <p><strong>Schemes:&nbsp;</strong>Alumni Continuing Education (ACE), Lifelong Learning Credit (L2C)</p>
  <p><strong>Funding:&nbsp;</strong>To be confirmed</p>
  <p><strong>School/Department:&nbsp;</strong>School of Business</a></p>
```

I want to store the values like below, but from page to page not all values will appear/be necessary:

```
var course_application_close = "15 June 2023"
var course_application_open = "01 May 2023"
var course_next_intake = "July 2023"
var course_areas_of_interests = "Business Administration"
var course_duration = "6 months"
var course_fees = 1536
var course_funding = "To be confirmed"
var course_lang = "English"
var course_schemes = "Alumni Continuing Education (ACE), Lifelong Learning Credit (L2C)"
var course_school = School of Business
var course_types = Part-time Undergraduate
```

But I don't know how to loop an appropriate IF statement AND trim the values I've been able to output individually but not the looping and IF:

var message = ""
message = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=infobox]')[0].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent
const valuesFromClass = [];
const titleFromClass = [];
for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('[class*=infobox]')[0].getElementsByTagName("p").length; i++) {
titleFromClass.push(document.querySelectorAll('[class*=infobox]')[0].getElementsByTagName("strong")[i].textContent)
valuesFromClass.push(document.querySelectorAll('[class*=infobox]')[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[i].textContent)
//console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[class*=infobox]')[0].getElementsByTagName(‘p’)[I].textContent)
}
console.log(valuesFromClass)

I'm able to define the "titleFromClass" which is the first portion but not the stores portion that I need, can anyone help?